# optaplanner results with even spread

Tags: optaplanner

Does anyone know using Optaplanner what the rule would be to evenly spread out the course scheduling?
eg:
I am trying to input 15 courses - some of which need to be in a specific order, then spread these 15 course as evenly as possible over the input time period.

If this type of scenario is documented somewhere, please just forward with the link, I really can't find any eaxmples

TIA
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the docs, look for **fairness/load balancing**.

The squared trick also works for spreads, for example optimal schedule:

- exam A on 1-FEB
- exam B on 4-FEB => 3 days between A and B => -3² = - 9
- exam C on 7-FEB => 3 days between B and C => -3² = - 9
- Total: - 18

Non optimal schedule:

- exam A on 1-FEB
- exam B on 3-FEB => 2 days between A and B => -2² = - 4
- exam C on 7-FEB => 4 days between B and C => -4² = - 16
- Total: - 20 (so worse than -18, which is what we want)

To combine this weighting with other constraints, see the tennis example and [read my blog post a couple of times](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2017/02/03/FormulaForMeasuringUnfairness.html).

Comment: Thank you for the information, definitely a bit out of my league here, but I shall do some more reading